# JS - Unity - Multiples of a Number from a Number

Tags: javascript, cycle, unityscript

I have a yield WaitForSeconds, transform.position.y=transform.position.y+1; cycle which constantly adds numbers.

At the bottom I will have 52 of these:

```
    function Update () {
        if (transform.position.y ? == 1) {
print ("Part2")
        }

        if (transform.position.y ? == 2) {
print ("Part3")
        }

        if (transform.position.y ? == 3) {
print ("Part4")
        }
    etc...
```

How do I set it so that to get it to say 'Part2', the transform.position.y has to be either 2, 54, 106, etc.. (onwards forever).
Much would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if ( transform.position.y == 2 || transform.position.y == 54 || transform.position.y == 106 ) {
   print ("Part2");
}
```

Comment: The thing is, this is the script which controls the score so if someone got a score of 30,450, the game wouldn't be able to recognize that score. I'm not so sure the equation to get it so that it can be ANY number in the pattern rather than a fixed set of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the mod operator (`%` in Javascript) which returns the [division remainder of two integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder).

For example:

- `7 % 2 = 1`

So `transform.position.y % 52` will do exactly what you want:

- `0 % 52 = 0`
- `1 % 52 = 1`
- `2 % 52 = 2`
- ...
- `51 & 52 = 51`
- `52 % 52 = 0`
- `53 % 52 = 1`
- `54 % 52 = 2`
- and so on...

To have it go from  `1-52` instead of `0-51`, you can just add one to the result.

All together:

```
function Update() {
    var part : int = transform.position.y % 52 + 1;
    print( "Part" + part.ToString() );
}
```